# Compiling gearman on Amazon Linux

Tags: gearman, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install gearman in the following way

```
sudo yum -y install libevent-devel gcc-c++ boost-devel libuuid-devel gperf mysql-devel
wget https://launchpad.net/gearmand/1.2/1.1.12/+download/gearmand-1.1.12.tar.gz
tar -xvzf gearmand-1.1.12.tar.gz
cd gearmand-1.1.12
./configure --with-mysql
```

It works well upto this point. Now I do

```
make
```

and I get the following errors

```
  CXX      libgearman/libgearman_libgearman_la-check.lo
    In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/move.h:57:0,
                     from /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                     from /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/utility:70,
                     from /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/algorithm:60,
                     from libgearman/check.cc:44:
    /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/type_traits:399:12: error: redefinition of 'struct std::is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>'
         struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes...) volatile>
                ^
    /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/type_traits:383:12: error: previous definition of 'struct std::is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>'
         struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>
                ^
    /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/type_traits:403:12: error: redefinition of 'struct std::is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes ..., ...)>'
         struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes......) volatile>
                ^
   /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/functional:1862:5: error: redefinition of 'template<class _Member, class _Class> std::_Mem_fn<_Tp _Class::*> std::__callable_functor(_Member _Class::* const&)'
     __callable_functor(_Member _Class::* const volatile &__p)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.3/functional:1852:5: error: 'template<class _Member, class _Class> std::_Mem_fn<_Tp _Class::*> std::__callable_functor(_Member _Class::* const&)' previously declared here
     __callable_functor(_Member _Class::* const &__p)
     ^
make[1]: *** [libgearman/libgearman_libgearman_la-check.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/var/tmp/gearmand-1.1.12'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Which libraries am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to update repositories

```
sudo yum -y update
```

Just in case, someone needs to install gearman along with the web ui and gearman manager, I prepared a set of scripts https://github.com/koustubh25/gearmanBuildScript